# c++ template function

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have following code:

```
void myfunc() 
{ 
} 
template <typename T> 
void check() 
{ 
} 

template <typename T> 
void checkT (T) 
{ 
    check<T>(); 
}
```

and so if I have in main function a call to `checkT(myfunc)` then that compiles, but if I have `check<myfunc>()` that doesn't work although it directly calls the first version. Can you please explain why it is so? The error is

> error: no matching function for call to 'check()'

Thanks!

Comment: To make things clear, give us an example of what you're explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `myfunc` is a value expression, not a type. You could do

```
check<decltype(myfunc)>();
```

though, or equivalently:

```
check<void(void)>();
```

See it live on [http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ANEre$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ANEre%240)

---

**PS.** In reply to the comment, I sense a bit of confusion between the function formal parameter and a template type parameter. Make it more explicit by writing:

```
template <typename T> 
void checkT (T somevalue) 
{ 
    check<T>();  // note: somevalue is never used!
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But my question is why it works when I call `checkT(myfunc)` which itself has call to `check<myfunc>()`?

Comment: Because it passes `T`, which is the _type_ of the argument, ***not*** the value (as the template _type_ argument)

Comment: I've tried to clarify in the answer, what seems to be the source of your confusion

Comment: So I guess what you are saying is that `checkT(myfunc)` and `check<void(void)>()` are the same? If so how can you explain output of http://liveworkspace.org/code/23fjAk$7  ?

Comment: Yes. And the difference you're are seeing is because of argument _decay_ to function-pointer, unless you pass by reference: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2LhVWO$1

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to do more reading on function pointers and decay stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance `checkT(myfunc)` it is able to deduce the type, `checkT` is really identical to `checkT( T value )` and so you are passing in `value` and `T` is being deduced. In the second case you are not supplying a type you can alter it like so to work:

```
check<decltype(myfunc)>() ;
```

you are actually supplying a `value` where you need a `type` in this case `void(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

`checkT(myfunc)` works because `myfunc` is a value. But the second fails because it is not a type, which the template parameters require. For example,

```
void checkT(T)
```

is the same as

```
void checkT(T t)
```

so that means the function passed is an object of type `T`. That is, `t` is the object and `T` is the type. In the template parameters of `check`, it requires an explicit specification of the *type*, not the object. So thus passing in an object would raise a compilation error. Just like passing in the number 5 where the explicit type `int` is expected.

You can use it as a type by wrapping it in a `decltype` expression:

```
check<decltype(myfunc)>();
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```